Let $(Y,T_{y})$ be a T1 and first countable and $(X,T_{x})$ as below , prove that a function between topological spaces X to Y is continuous iff
Sorry if its elementary, but here goes.
Let X be uncountable and $x_{0}$ be an arbitrary point of X, $T_{x}$ is the topology generated by the following basis
$\beta $ = {${x}$ such that $x \neq x_0$} $\bigcup$ {$ A \subseteq X$ such that $ X \setminus A$ is countable and $x_0 \in A$}
Prove that a function $f : X \rightarrow Y $ is continuous iff the set {$x \in X$ such that $f(x) \neq f(x_0)$} is countable.
I`ve been trying to think that if Y is T1 then every element is the intersection of all open sets (either in the topology or in the basis) that contains it and if Y satisfies the first countability axiom, then the inverse image of any element of Y is the intersection of a countable amount of open sets in X  (since f is continuous).
From here I think I need help to continue. Can someone clarify how to prove it? Thanks in advance.

Let $y_0 = f(x_0)$. Given an open set $V \subseteq Y$ such that $y_0 \notin V$, we have $x_0 \notin f^{-1}[V]$ so that preimage is clearly open. Thus $f$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of every open neighborhood of $y_0$ is open in $X$.
Now we show the equivalence. First assume that $f$ is continuous and take the countable local basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $Y$ at $y_0$. Since $Y$ is $T_1$, we have that $\bigcap \mathcal{B} = \{ y_0 \}$. Consequently,
$$f^{-1}[ \{ y_0 \} ] = \bigcap \{ f^{-1}[B] : B \in \mathcal{B} \}.$$
Since each $f^{-1}[B]$ is open in $X$, it contains all but countably many elements of $X$. Hence the same is true about $f^{-1}[ \{ y_0 \} ]$, proving the first implication.
Now assume that $\{ x \in X : f(x) \neq y_0 \} = X \setminus f^{-1}[ \{ y_0 \}]$ is countable. Then for each open neighborhood $V \subseteq Y$ of $y_0$ we have that $X \setminus f^{-1}[V]$ is contained in $X \setminus f^{-1}[ \{ y_0 \} ]$ so it is countable too, hence $f^{-1}[V]$ is open in $X$. Thus $f$ is continuous.
